# How to view changes in EF-CodeFirst before they are committed?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, code-first

I am trying to snoop on changes which are being persisted in EF-Code First **before** they are committed.

If we break during `SaveChanges` (as below) and drill down the watch (below below) you get to the non-public collection `ObjectStateManager._deletedEntityStore` which lists the persited items which are to be deleted.

This would be ideal for what I need but it is non-public. Does anyone know of any other way to get at this information?

(`this.Units.Local` is not sufficient.)

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{   
    public DbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }  
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        // Break here...
    }
}
```

`this.ChangeTracker._internalContext.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager._deletedEntityStore`

Cheers,
T

Comment: "I am trying to snoop on changes which are being persisted in EF-Code First before they are committed." - why?

Comment: I want to soft-delete certain things but I want it to happen transparently. My example (_addedEntryStore) prob wasn't the best, will update... :)

Comment: This question really doesn't have anything to do with Code First - the problem and solution are about Entity Framework's DbContext which works with any model mechanism (Code, Model, Database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to the underlying ObjectContext by casting your DbContext as IObjectContextAdapter.  From there you should be able to hook up to the ObjectStateManager.

In fact, if the underlying ObjectContext is really important you can expose it as a public property. Like so:

```
public ObjectContext UnderlyingContext
{ 
    get
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
    }
}
```